# Aptitude: how to disable warning about recommended packages?

Tags: aptitude

Aptitude keeps telling me the following message:

```
 The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed
```

However, I am not interested in this warning.

How to disable missing warnings about recommended packages in aptitude?

Comment: It does not seem to be possible at all: see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=953410#10

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `--without-recommends` flag.

For a permanent solution, you can set

```
Aptitude::Ignore-Recommends-Important "true";
```

in your configuration file (`~/.aptitude/config` or system wide `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*`) as specified [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s05.en.html)